# posting and getting parameters using curl

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to substitute passing parameters using url (eg. .../?id=123) with curl. ignore if using curl is not possible.

i tried looking for examples online but i could only see on how to post data but not getting it. i got this over one of the site online but i lost its reference.

```
                        $post_data['ID'] = '1';

                        //traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
                        foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
                        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
                        }

                        //create the final string to be posted using implode()
                        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

                        //create cURL connection
                        $curl_connection = curl_init('posturl.php');

                        //set options
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

                        //set data to be posted
                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

                        //perform our request8
                        $curlresult = curl_exec($curl_connection);

                        //show information regarding the request
                        // print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
                        echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                        //close the connection
                        curl_close($curl_connection);
```

how do i get the parameters from posturl.php

does anyone has an example to post and get using curl?

Answer (score 0):

`cURL` is mainly used for retrieving the HTML Rendered from the `HTTP POST` method. And you have done is really well. Now what exactly you wanna retrieve? Parameters from the `posturl.php`? Then in the end you can use this code right:

```
foreach($post_items as $parameter => $value)
    echo "The value of $parameter is $value.\n";
```

I am not sure if I understood the question, but this is the way I can help you out. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. usually if you would pass parameters using url, you would do a <a href="posturl.php?id=123">clickme</a> but i'm trying to sub it with curl. that's what i'm trying to do. i will work on your method right now.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('posturl.php');
```

with

```
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init("posturl.php?$post_string");
```

and comment

```
//curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```